# In BCS superconductors, superfluid part = Condensed Cooper Pairs? normal part = Bogoliubov quasiparticles?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, phase-transition, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

I'm studying superconductivity and BCS theory. There are two pictures of superconductivity electric transport:

1. Two-fluid model: superconductivity electron part + normal electron part
2. BCS theory: Condensed Cooper Pairs + Bogoliubov quasiparticles

What is the relationship between these two pictures? Is one-to-one correspondence?

Answer (score 0):

The supercurrent is carried by Cooper pairs: the normal electrons are still fermions in a filled band so for every one at $+\mathbf{k}$ there's one at $-\mathbf{k}$ which precludes and net momentum transfer. Cooper pairs are bosons, they don't have to obey this, and can carry net momentum and hence current.

About the two fluid model, see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/670915/help-in-understanding-superconductivity/670974#670974), but a good plot is:

[image]

which is taken from [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-13713-1_5), and shows the electron density being divided into $n_s$ and $n_n$, but it is however misleading as it suggests that there's $n_0$ normal electrons at $T_c$ and they are *all* converted into Cooper pairs ("super electrons"). To correct this, in the text they say:

> Here $n_0$ is the superconducting electron density at $T = 0$ K.

which is quite sneaky, but basically means they are going "the other way around": whatever Cooper pairs there are at $T=0$, they call that $n_0$, and they say that these would be normal electrons at $T=T_c$.